# std::mutex - синхронизация одной или нескольких переменных?

Tags: c++

Не могу понять, один и тот же std::muteх одновременно можно использовать только для синхронизации одной переменной или неограниченного числа переменных ?

Comment: mutex синхронизирует участок кода между lock и unlock, а не перменные

Comment: @user7860670, да, прошу прощение, просто, как частный случай пример привел - участок кода для доступа для чтения или записи в переменную.

Comment: Код, реализующий mutex, ничего не знает о переменных в программе

Answer (score 3):

Конечно для неограниченного.

Представьте, что у вас под мьютексом работа с двумя переменными. Если бы он мог синхронихировать только одну, то как бы он определил, какую их двух?

Comment: Вы имеете ввиду участок кода под мьютексом в котором две переменные ?

Comment: @Optimus1 Да, именно так.